# How to write tab-delimited text into excel sheet programmatically?

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have an object of StringBuilder which stores a tab-delimited text and I want to import it to an Excel sheet. In my application it can be achieved in two ways. From a dialog one can choose either copying the text to the clipboard (and then he/she can open a new Excel sheet and simply paste in Excel) or saving it directly to an Excel workbook. First option works perfectly fine and I want to implement the behaviour for saving directly.

The only way that I found on the internet is storing each line of the text to the string array and then each index of array will be new row in Excel sheet, so I can write each row by iterating the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < exportStrings.Count; i++)
{
     Excel.Range currentRange = (Excel.Range)xlWsh.Cells[i + 1, 1];
     currentRange.Value = exportStrings[i];
}
```

But then it causes a problem for the first option. Since the text is now stored as a string array, I cannot easily copy it to the clipboard. That is why I decided to keep my text stored as a stringbuilder. I also tried to write the text to the very first cell in the Excel sheet, (since it works when I paste the text to first cell in Excel sheet manually in the first option) but it doesn't recognise the new line charactes.

```
Excel.Range currentRange = (Excel.Range)xlWsh.Cells[1, 1];
currentRange.Value2 = exportStrings.ToString();
```

Any idea how it can be done using stringbuilder? or how can I make it to recognise new line character?

Comment: How do you get your text into `StringBuilder`?

Comment: @trailmax stringbuilder.AppendLine(nextRow);

Answer (score 0):

You can always extract a string from your string builder, and then split it into lines, if you need a string array:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//fill sb with whatever data you need
if (option1)
{
    //use stringbuilder, copy to clipboared
}
if (option2)
{
    //convert to string array
    String allText = sb.ToString();
    string[] textLines = allText.Split(Environment.NewLine);
    //write to Excel...
}
```

Admittedly, this is not perfect in terms of efficiency: You are creating an intermediate string, and then you again allocate memory for the string array. But I am going to assume that you are dealing with a limited amount of data, and that the interaction with Excel takes more time anyway than a few object allocations.